# Inserção de registro com webservice retorna erro mas insere no banco

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, apache-cordova

Olá, eu tenho uma função javascript que faz uma chamada ajax pra um arquivo php que deve inserir os registros no banco MySQL. Pois bem, eu estou conseguindo inserir os registros porém a função está me retornando um erro. Alguém sabe dizer o motivo do erro? Desde já agradeço.

**Erro exibido no alert:**

> Resposta: {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

**funcoes.js**

```
function salvar(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {operationType: 'insert', nome: $('#nome').val(), sobrenome: $('#sobrenome').val(), idade: $('#idade').val() },
    url: 'http://localhost/projetos/wstest/cadastrar.php',
    ContentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(response){
        alert('Resposta: '+JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    error: function(err){
        alert('Resposta: '+JSON.stringify(err));
        alert('Erro ao inserir registro!');
    }
});}
```

**cadastrar.php**

```
include './conexao.php';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$link = conectar();

$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['nome']);
$sobrenome = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['sobrenome']);
$idade = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['idade']);

$query = "INSERT INTO `usuario`(`nome`, `sobrenome`, `idade`) "
    . "VALUES ('$nome','$sobrenome','$idade')";

$res = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if(isset($_POST['operationType']))
{

    if ($_POST['operatioType'] == "insert") 
{        
    $query = "INSERT INTO `usuario`(`nome`, `sobrenome`, `idade`) "
            . "VALUES ('$nome','$sobrenome','$idade')";

    $res = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if ($res == true) 
    {
        $resultado = 1;

        return $resultado;
    } 
    else
    {
        $resultado = 0;

        return $resultado;
    }

    echo json_encode($resultado);
}

else if($_POST['operationType'] == "login")
{

}
}
else
{
    echo "Formato de requisição inválido! O aplicativo não conseguiu se comunicar "
. "de maneira correta com o servidor.";
}
```

Comment: Não me parece um erro no PHP, ele está bem simples. O que pode ser é o retorno não ser um JSON válido, dia o jquery não está conseguindo dar parse nele. Tente mudar o tipo de dataType: 'json' para 'html', por exemplo, e veja se o erro continua. Outro detalhe importante é que o script pode estar jogando lixo no buffer, por exemplo, um warnning, e isso vai zicar a saida json, então precisa tratar essas saídas errôneas do buffer. Mais um detalhe importantíssimo, verifique a possibilidade de utilizar PDO ao invés de mysqli, além de inseguro, está descontinuado

Comment: Vejo que não precisa converter para JSON, apenas retornar o valor da variável `$resultado`.

Answer (score 0):

o erro pode estar aqui:

```
    else if($_POST['operationType'] == "login")
{

}
}
else
{
    echo "Formato de requisição inválido! O aplicativo não conseguiu se comunicar "
. "de maneira correta com o servidor.";
}
```

tem uma chave fechando a mais, tente apagar ela e veja se o que acontece.
e adicione alguma coisa if == login, mesmo que seja uma variável fazia ex `$a = "";`